# why doesn't scala recognize com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem

Tags: scala, netbeans, vaadin

I'm trying to create a Vaadin window with a MenuBar using Scala.  I'm getting a compiler error that indicates that the com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem import can't be found. I've looked at the Vaadin library (6.4.8), and it appears that the class is there:

```
com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar$Command.class
com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar$MenuItem.class
com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.class
```

Here is the class structure from the MenuBar source:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ClientWidget(value = VMenuBar.class, loadStyle = LoadStyle.LAZY)
public class MenuBar extends AbstractComponent { 
   ... 
   public interface Command extends Serializable { ... }
   public class MenuItem implements Serializable { ... }

}
```

For demo purposes, here's a sample Scala class:

```
import com.vaadin.Application
import com.vaadin.ui.Button
import com.vaadin.ui.Window
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.Command
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem

class MyVaadinApplication extends Application
{

    private var window : Window = null

    override def init() =
    {
        window = new Window("My Scala Vaadin Application")
        setMainWindow(window)
        window.addComponent(new Button("Click Me"))
    }

}
```

And here's the resulting error when I try to compile it:

```
/Users/jstanford/Development/NetBeansProjects/TraderDashboard/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
Compiling 2 source files to /Users/jstanford/Development/NetBeansProjects/TraderDashboard/target/classes at 1291973683915
[ERROR]MyVaadinApplication.scala:7: error: MenuItem is not a member of com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem
       ^
```

Can anyone spot the problem here?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inner classes cannot be imported as usual it is appropriate for Java. Just specify type projections as it's done for Button#ClickEvent type:

```
import com.vaadin._
import ui._
import Button._

class MyScalaVaadinApplication extends Application {
  val window = new Window("My Vaadin Application")

  def init {
    window.addComponent(new Button("Click Me", new ClickListener {
      def buttonClick(clickEvent: Button#ClickEvent): Unit = window.showNotification("Just a message")
    }))

    setMainWindow(window)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example showing what's going on.

Java:

```
package a;
public class Outer { public class Inner {} }
```

Scala:

```
import a.Outer
import a.Outer.Inner // causes *Inner is not a member of a.Outer*
```

Notice that *Inner*, like *MenuBar.MenuItem*, is a non-static inner class and as such is associated with one instance of *Outer*. But Scala allows us to import *Inner* using a instance of *Outer*:

```
import a.Outer
import a.Outer.Inner

object dummy {
  val o = new Outer
  val o2 = new Outer
  import o.Inner
  val i = new Inner
  val i2 = new o2.Inner
}
```

If we could just `import a.Outer.Inner` how would the compiler know to which instance of *Outer* is *Inner* supposed to belong to?

Hope the issue has been cleared.